# XSLT Multiple Conditions

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have this XSLT 2.0 template:

```
<xsl:template match="para[
    not(ancestor::p) 
    and not(ancestor::div) 
    and not(ancestor::paragraph)
    ]">
    <p class="para">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

It does what I need it to do: it prevents an HTML `<p>` in a `<p>`. But it is verbose and I suppose there is a more concise way to write it.

Is there a better way to write the multiple ancestor tests? I tried a union..that didn't work of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="para[not(ancestor::p|ancestor::div|ancestor::paragraph)]">
    <p class="para">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

Alternatively

```
<xsl:template match="para">
    <p class="para">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="para[ancestor::p|ancestor::div|ancestor::paragraph]" />
<!-- or whatever you want to do in that case, <xsl:apply-templates/> maybe -->
```

Comment: +1. In the second case it would be helpful to explain that the second template has a higher implicit priority because of the specificity of its match pattern. However this introduces hidden dependencies that could easily get broken later, e.g. if someone needed to change the `match="para"` pattern for some reason. My recommendation when using template priorities is to make them explicit using the `priority=` attribute.

Comment: @LarsH I've gotten a bit weary of explaining match expression specificity, but yes, you're right. Also with your second point, which is a problem inherent to any blacklisting/whitelisting. Up to a certain transformation complexity it would remain manageable, at some point it might lead to unexpected behavior.

Comment: I agree with you. Besides complexity, it also depends on the number of people on the project, their level of experience in XSLT, etc. I wouldn't tell an expert doing a personal project that he should avoid using implicit priority. But I think when introducing a solution that relies on it, to someone who may not be aware, it's important that they know the issue exists. Then they can make an informed decision. What makes this case worthy of extra care is that if a bug occurs, it's very difficult to discover why, if you're not aware of the default priority mechanism.

Comment: I would use this solution but would probably write the pattern as `match="p//para | div//para | paragraph//para"`.

Comment: That's a variant I did not think of. And shorter, too, at least for short element names. Thanks for the addition! (In any case, my "union of ancestors" is probably less efficient, too, though it would take a very large input doc to see it.)